# How do I use XLOOKUP for multiple criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, xlookup

my question is simple enough. It involves, using `XLOOKUP` formula. So, following is the issue, I'm facing.

- I have ***master data*** sheet, which I'm using for the lookup reference.
- In sheet ***XLOOKUP test***, I'm looking up the `Task Completion Status` for the search keys `Sl No.` in cell `C3` and `Date` in cell `C4`.

I've applied the formula-

> `XLOOKUP($C$3&$C$4, 'Master Data'!$A$2:$A$9&'Master Data'!$C$2:$C$9, 'Master Data'!$D$2:$D$9, , 0, 1)`

But, it pops out an `#N/A` error message with `Array arguments to XLOOKUP are of different size.`.

So what am I doing wrong ?

Here's a link to my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15z3ezJDCYa2-p-07dUMLx3Vlut99XSrsxdjYRRmufY8/edit#gid=1389316845), if needed.

Comment: Exact copy of [How do I use XLOOKUP for multiple lookup criteria?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/168262/269219)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To combine *columns* into a compound key, you need to wrap the formula in `arrayformula()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( xlookup(C3 & C4, 'Master Data'!A2:A9 & 'Master Data'!C2:C9, 'Master Data'!D2:D9) )`

Alternatively, use `filter()`:

`=filter('Master Data'!D2:D9, C3 = 'Master Data'!A2:A9, C4 = 'Master Data'!C2:C9)`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15z3ezJDCYa2-p-07dUMLx3Vlut99XSrsxdjYRRmufY8/edit#gid=1613462223).

Comment: Thanks, your solution does help with the problem. So, now my question now is, why do we need to wrap `XLOOKUP` with `ARRAYFORMULA` when dealing with _compound keys_ as oppose to when looking up for a _single key_ ?

Comment: It's not the `xlookup()` that requires wrapping but the `&` operator. You can do the same like this: `=xlookup(C3 & C4, arrayformula('Master Data'!A2:A9 & 'Master Data'!C2:C9), 'Master Data'!D2:D9)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can even use the Multiple Criteria Boolean Expressions XLOOKUP functionality

=XLOOKUP(1,('Master Data'!A2:A9=C3)*('Master Data'!$C$2:$C$9=C4),'Master Data'!D2:D9,,0)

Comment: This formula will error out in Google Sheets. To make it work, wrap it in `arrayformula()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).